# How to find iBeacon Triggering Apps for IoT Devices Unrelated to Marketing?

Tags: beacons

I hope this an OK question to ask.  I know it's a bit meta and vague, but hear me out...

Ever since iBeacon technology came out, I've been hunting for reliable iOS apps that can trigger actions on a room-scale level.  I started out long ago with simple reminders.  Since then I've moved on to home (and work) automation via iBeacon-aware apps that can POST webhook requests upon entry/exit.  Some iBeacon-aware apps can even interact with specific brands of IoT devices, like smart switches and bulbs, directly.

My question is, does anyone know of a good way to find these apps without sifting through the sea of marketing-related apps?

Searching the apple app store and googling produces paltry results, many of which claim to do beacon-related things, but are either outdated, buggy, confusingly complex, support limited beacon brands, have very limited features, or have simply fallen off the app store.

I'm currently using 5 different beacon apps that have taken me years to find.  I occasionally search for more and I struggle to find search terms that yield good results.  I've found that some apps with the best features or the best reliability were not made specifically for iBeacons, but support them.

(It would be nice if iBeacons were actually somewhat obfuscated too and generally support detecting of any bluetooth signal that could be used as a trigger (e.g. detecting one of those car computer-port dongles or BT speakers).  Is there a way to find apps that do that?)

Lastly, it would be great if there was a way to search specifically for iBeacon apps that have built-in Kalman filtering to cut down on repeated entry/exit triggering.

If you think this question is not appropriate here, please comment and I'll take it down.  I'm just frustrated and I want to know if other people have a good way of locating iBeacon apps.

Comment: Incidentally, the coolest iBeacon app I’ve used thus far *was* Beecon (note the spelling), but with the latest iOS 12 update, it has become prone to crashing either when you launch it or sometimes when it tries to issue a POST in the background, thus it’s no longer reliable. And app support for it is nil.